# Understanding the closure of a set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> What is the closure of this set?
>   $$\{(t_1,\dots,t_n) \in [0,1[^n : t_1 < \dots < t_n\}$$

From Wikipedia:
*For $S$ a subset of a Euclidean space, $x$ is a point of closure of $S$ if every open ball centered at $x$ contains a point of $S$ (this point may be $x$ itself).*

How am I supposed to find these points? I think the closure of the above set is a full simplex with vertices in $[0,1]^n$ (checked "graphically" only for $n=2$ and $n=3$).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I think it should be easier to use the (equivalent) definition that the closure of a set is the set of all points which are limits of convergent sequences of points of the considered set.